# Grouping the same recurring items that occur in a row from list

Tags: python, list, grouping, recurring

For instance, we have a list like this:

```
L = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item1", "item2", "item4", "item4", "item4"]
```

I want to pack them into list of tuples of the form:

```
[("item1", 1), ("item2", 1), ("item3", 3),... ("item1", 1)]
```

I've already developed an algorithm which does something similar, to get:

```
{item1: 2, item2: 2, ...}
```

(it finds all the occurrences and counts them, even if they aren't neighbours...)

However, I want it to groups only those items which have the same *and* are neighbours (i.e. occur in a row together), how could I accomplish this?

*It's not that I don't know how to do it but I tend to write code that is long and I want an elegant and uncomplicated solution in this case.*

Comment: `item1: 1, item2:1, item3:3....item1: 1` would not be a dictionary... (it has more than one of the same key)

Comment: Sorry about that. That is true. Ignore the fact that I've written that must be a dictionary. It is not a requirement. It can be in the form of tuples. So the order is important ofcourse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), items are repeated so you might not be able to store all values in a dictionary, as `item1` & `item2` are repeated:

```
In [21]: l = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item3", "item3", "item1", "item2", "item4", "item4", "item4"]

In [22]: for k,g in groupby(l):
    print "{0}:{1}".format(k,len(list(g)))
   ....:     
item1:1
item2:1
item3:3
item1:1
item2:1
item4:3
```

Comment: No need for a key function in this case.

Comment: Great.Thanks.I was looking for the groupby function indeed. And yes it is no use for key lambda function. It works absolutely flawlessly:)

Comment: You can also use [ilen](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/seqs.html#ilen) from [funcy](https://github.com/Suor/funcy) library instead of `len(list(...))` for speed.

Answer (score 5):

This is also using [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (a generator version):

```
from itertools import groupby
counts = ((k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in groupby(l))
>>> list(counts)
[('item1', 1),
 ('item2', 1),
 ('item3', 3),
 ('item1', 1),
 ('item2', 1),
 ('item4', 3)]
```

Comment: `len(list(g))` is shorter than `sum(1 for _ in g)`, +1 anyway.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary it's shorter, but I figured it could be faster; I tend to think it's a good idea to avoid creating a list just to count its elements. Thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: Good point, jut timed them, `sum(1 for _ in g)`<`len(tuple(g))`<`len(list(g))`, learned something new today. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
python 3.2
from itertools import groupby

>>> [(i,(list(v)).count(i)) for i,v in groupby(L)]
```