# Parsing specific columns from a dataset in python

Tags: python, parsing, numpy, scipy

I have a dataset with multiple columns and I am only interested in analyzing the data from six of the columns. It is in a txt file, and I want to load the file and pull out the following columns (0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7) with the headings (time, mode, event, xcoord, ycoord, phi).  There are ten columns total, Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
1385940076332   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076336   2   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076339   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076342   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076346   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076350   2   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076353   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076356   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
```

When I use the following code to parse the data into columns, it only appears to count the data- but I would like to be able to list the data for further analysis. Here is the code I am using from @alko:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filtered.txt', header=None, false_values=None, sep='\s+')[[0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7]]
df.columns = ['time', 'mode', 'event', 'xcoord', 'ycoord', 'phi']
print df
```

Here is what that code returns:

```
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
Int64Index: 115534 entries, 0 to 115533
Data columns (total 6 columns): 
time      115534  non-null values
mode      115534  non-null values
event     115534  non-null values
xcoord    115534  non-null values
ycoord    115534  non-null values
phi       115534  non-null values
dtypes: float64(3), int64(2), object(1)
```

So the goal is to pull out these 6 columns from the 10 original, label them, and list them.

Comment: You have to check delimiter. Then `str.split(delimiter)`.

Comment: The delimiter is one space in between each column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)' [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) parser:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
s = """1385940076332   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076336   2   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076339   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076342   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076346   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076350   2   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076353   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076356   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.# 000000    0.000000"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s),header=None, sep='\s+')[[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]]
df.columns = ['time', 'mode', 'event', 'xcoord', 'ycoord', 'phi']
print df
#             time mode           event  xcoord     ycoord  phi
# 0  1385940076332    M  subject_avatar     -30 -59.028107  180
# 1  1385940076336    M  subject_avatar     -30 -59.028107  180
# 2  1385940076339    M  subject_avatar     -30 -59.028107  180
# 3  1385940076342    M  subject_avatar     -30 -59.028107  180
# 4  1385940076346    M  subject_avatar     -30 -59.028107  180
# 5  1385940076350    M  subject_avatar     -30 -59.028107  180
# 6  1385940076353    M  subject_avatar     -30 -59.028107  180
# 7  1385940076356    M  subject_avatar     -30 -59.028107  180
```

Note, that I corrected columns indices, as it seems that ones provided by You in the question are not correct.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! How can I apply this piece of code to my entire dataset instead of just the piece that I copied and pasted?

Comment: @Julia You should be able to provide `'/Users/Lab/Desktop/vr.txt'` instead of  `StringIO` object. Don't forget to handle header if exists  and skip rows if needed. I updated link to point to read_csv docs, you'll find details there.

Comment: Thanks, I think that would have worked, except my dataset is not uniform, there are lines with fewer than 10 columns interspersed throughout and ideally I want to distinguish the data before those lines from the data that comes after. I will ask a separate question to address this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I edited my original question to ask how I can view the data now that it is separated into the 6 different columns.  I have tried to use 'print df.values', but that is not giving the complete data.

Comment: @Julia You'd better don't edit original question but ask a new one (it's free :) ), as this invalidates already given answers. Also it helps keep one question per topic, wich makes this site more useful for further reference.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! (I am new to the site)

Comment: @Julia you're welcome! For your second question, your dataframe is loaded but is too big to be printed out, that's why info only is printed. Consult for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/15006495/1265154